# excel vba getting the row,cell value from selection.address

Tags: vba, excel

```
For i = 1 To 20

  '' select the cell in question
  Cells.Find(...).Select

  '' get the cell address

  CellAddr = Selection.Address(False, False, xlR1C1) 



Next
```

The above is my code for searching a spread sheet to find a specific string and then select it. I'd like to get the address of the cell using `Selection.Address` which, in this case, returns something along the lines of `R[100]C`. Is there a way I can split that result in to row and column values so I can manipulate them in code? I'd like, for example to add 14 rows to the selected cells row value. I believe `CellAddr` will be a Range object so it may work I'm just fuzzy on the implementation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Dim f as Range

Set f=ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(...)

If Not f Is Nothing then
    msgbox "Row=" & f.Row & vbcrlf & "Column=" & f.Column
Else
    msgbox "value not found!"
End If
```

Answer (score 16):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
Sub getRowCol()

    Range("A1").Select ' example

    Dim col, row
    col = Split(Selection.Address, "$")(1)
    row = Split(Selection.Address, "$")(2)

    MsgBox "Column is : " & col
    MsgBox "Row is : " & row

End Sub
```

Comment: Surely we should be able reference: Selection.Address.Row and Selection.Address.Column,right?   It doesn't work for me, but I can't imagine the VBA gods would force us to use Split for such a trival task??